# How To fix That Json JQuery Ajax Call undefined Issuse

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Php:-

```
$data = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($avatar)){
    $row_data = array(
            'image' => $row['image']
    );
    array_push($data, $row_data);
 }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($comments)){
    $row_data = array(
            'comment' => $row['comments']
    );
    array_push($data, $row_data);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

jQuery Ajax:-

```
$(".comment").click(function(){

    var id  =  $(this).data("id");
    var name = $("#username_"+id).val();

    function json(){  
        alert('loading please wait');                
    }

    if(name==''){
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "comments",
            data:{comments:name,parent:id},
            success: function(json){

                $(".cmt_output").html(""+json["comments"]+""+json["image"]+"");

            }
        });
    }
});
```

json Array Format:-

```
[
    {"image":"1510553412_User_Avatar_2.png"},
    {"comment":"Welcome"},
    {"comment":"Nice"},
    {"comment":"Nice"},
    {"comment":"Nice too...."}
]
```

Html:-

```
<div class="cmt_output"></div>
```

Output:-

```
undefined undefined
```

Output i want:

```
1510553412_User_Avatar_2.png
Welcome
Nice
Nice
Nice too
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `success` function to:

```
success: function(json)
{
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    json.forEach(function (item, index){
        if(item.image !== undefined)
        {
            $(".cmt_output").append(item.image);
        }
            $(".cmt_output").append(item.comments);
        })

}
```

Or instead of `json = JSON.parse(json);` use:

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(json)
{
    json.forEach(function (item, index){
        if(item.image !== undefined)
        {
            $(".cmt_output").append(item.image);
        }
            $(".cmt_output").append(item.comments);
        })

}
```

Comment: Thanks For Your answer.

Comment: @JohnBright If the answer was helpful please be sure to accept it.

Comment: @JohnBright You haven't accepted any answer yet. You can accept an answer by clicking on `gray tick` under the voting buttons on the side of the answer.